# How to use Two spinner in one activity in android with php mysql

Tags: android, spinner

i have developing android app for E-commerce.i have use two spinner in one activity for first spinner fetch category to `json` .It select country based fetch sub category to `php` `json` but i don't know this concept how to implement this concept please help

```
public class ProductForm extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner prospin, prospin1;
    EditText pdctname, pdctbrand, pdctmodel, pdctdiscount, pdctdisvalidity, pdctprice;
    ImageView pfile;
    Button pdctphoto, pdctupload, pdctsubmit;
    String val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9;
    String Spinner_url1 = "category url";
    String Spinner_url2 = “sub category url”
    ClassJSONParser json = new ClassJSONParser();
    private JSONArray data = null;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private String myJSON;
    String monthname = "cat_name";
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    static String strSDCardPathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM" + "/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_form);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        spindisplaydata();
        createFolder();
        prospin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        prospin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        prospin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        pdctname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pname);
        pdctbrand = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pbrand);
        pdctmodel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pmodel);
        pdctdiscount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pdiscount);
        pdctdisvalidity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pdiscountvalidity);
        pdctprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.proprice);
        pfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pfilepath);
        pdctphoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prophoto);
        pdctphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        pdctupload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proupload);
        pdctsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosubmit);
        pdctsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                val1 = pdctname.getText().toString();
                val2 = pdctbrand.getText().toString();
                val3 = pdctmodel.getText().toString();
                val4 = pdctdiscount.getText().toString();
                val5 = pdctdisvalidity.getText().toString();
                val6 = pdctprice.getText().toString();
                val7 = prospin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                val8 = prospin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                val9 = pfile.getResources().toString();

                if (val1.equals("") || val2.equals("") || val3.equals("") || val4.equals("") || val5.equals("") || val6.equals("")) {

                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void spindisplaydata() {
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            private String line;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                InputStream is = null;
                String result = null;
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                String key12 = "3015";
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", key12));
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String php_url = Spinner_url1;
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(php_url);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Invalid IP Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                myJSON = result;
                showList1();

            }

        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();

    }

    private void showList1() {
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> lista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> data;
        try {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            JSONArray jArray = json_data.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                data.put("catname", json_data.getString(monthname));

                lista.add(data);
                arrayList.add(json_data.getString(monthname));
                Log.e("Catnames", "" + monthname);
                Log.e("Catnames", "" + arrayList);


            }

            SpinAdapter1 adapter = new SpinAdapter1(lista, ProductForm.this, arrayList);
            prospin.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag2", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }


    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(strSDCardPathName);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //*** Rename File
            String strNewName = "MyPicture.jpg";
            String NewPath = strSDCardPathName + strNewName;
            Log.e("Pathname", "" + NewPath);

            //*** Resize Images
            try {
                ResizeImages(mCurrentPhotoPath, NewPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(NewPath);
            pfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            GalleryAddPic();
        }
    }

    private void GalleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);

        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    public static void ResizeImages(String sPath, String sTo) throws IOException {

        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sPath);
        photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 720, 600, false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        File f = new File(sTo);
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();

        File file = new File(sPath);
        file.delete();

    }

    public static void createFolder() {
        File folder = new File(strSDCardPathName);
        try {
            // Create folder
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedItemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(ProductForm.this, selectedItemText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_name_sub", prospin.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            JSONObject obj1 = json.membuatHttpRequest(Spinner_url2, "GET", params);
            data = obj1.getJSONArray(TAG_SEMUA_KOMENTAR);
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


}
```

Comment: how to connect first spinner dependent second spinner fetch data

Answer (score 1):

use this Library : [Searchable Spinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner)

this is very simple Spinner lib you only need to set list of string in adapter and set adapter to spinner after that onItemSelect of Spinner you can get the first spinner Selected Item ID and based on this you can fetch data of second Spinner!